# Getting a syntax error reading a JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, file, fetch-api

I'm trying to read data from a json file that I have saved in my root folder and this is the error I am getting:

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 2 column 2 of the JSON data

The code is:

```
function getData(){
      fetch("./data.json")
      .then(response => {
          return response.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
          console.log(data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
      })
  }
  
 getData();
```

Comment: This means your JSON file is formatted incorrectly. Paste the file into jsonlint.com.

Comment: at a guess, you have a trailing comma after a property in an object - valid in javascript, invalid in JSON

Comment: Can you point it out from the code?

Comment: It's not in your code, it's in your `data.json` file

Comment: I think you're right